# Ruby more transparent and clean code when using map

Tags: ruby, jira-rest-api

I've got a simple 2 methods which fetch data from Jira project with assigned tasks to user which left to be done. Right now I fetched `customfields` from Jira API (`time_to_resolution` and desired_time_to_resolution) and it doesn't look good, is it possible to do it in a more clean, readable way?

```
def assigned_task_list
  assigned_tasks.map do |issue|
    fields = issue.fields

    {
      key: issue.key,
      desired_time_to_resolution: issue.customfield_14777.dig('ongoingCycle', 'remainingTime', 'friendly'),
      time_to_resolution: issue.customfield_10031.dig('ongoingCycle', 'remainingTime', 'friendly'),
      name: fields.dig('assignee', 'name'),
      email: fields.dig('assignee', 'emailAddress'),
      status: fields.dig('status', 'name')
    }
  end
end
```

The `assigned_tasks` method below:

```
def assigned_tasks
  project.issues.select do |issue|
    issue.fields.dig('status', 'name') != 'Done' &&
      issue.fields.dig('assignee', 'name')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create several methods and hide the logic inside them.

```rb
def assigned_task_list
  assigned_tasks.map do |issue|
    {
      key: issue.key,
      desired_time_to_resolution: desired_time_to_resolution(issue),
      time_to_resolution: time_to_resolution(issue),
      name: name(issue),
      email: email(issue),
      status: status(issue)
    }
  end
end

private

def desired_time_to_resolution(issue)
  issue.customfield_14777.dig('ongoingCycle', 'remainingTime', 'friendly')
end

def time_to_resolution(issue)
  issue.customfield_10031.dig('ongoingCycle', 'remainingTime', 'friendly')
end

def name(issue)
  issue.fields.dig('assignee', 'name')
end

def email(issue)
  issue.fields.dig('assignee', 'emailAddress')
end

def status(issue)
  issue.fields.dig('status', 'name')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

That might be a good opportunity to test brand new *Ruby 2.7* destructuring aka [pattern matching feature](https://medium.com/cedarcode/ruby-pattern-matching-1e84cab3b44a):

```rb
def assigned_task_list
  assigned_tasks.map do |issue|
    case issue
    in {
      key: key,
      customfield_14777: {
        ongoingCycle: { remainingTime: { friendly: desired_time_to_resolution }}
      },
      customfield_10031: {
        ongoingCycle: { remainingTime: { friendly: time_to_resolution }}
      },
      fields: {
        assignee: { name: name, emailAddress: email },
        status: { name: status }
      }
    }
      {
        key: key, 
        desired_time_to_resolution: desired_time_to_resolution,
        time_to_resolution: time_to_resolution,
        name: name,
        email: email,
        status: status
      }
  end
end
```

The same should apply to `assigned_tasks`.

Comment: I forgot to add that this has to be in `Ruby 2.5.0` because I use AWS lambda later on which required that specific version of ruby

Comment: Then this answer would not apply in your particular case, but I am to leave it here for the sake of future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new class which encapsulates the transformation/extraction logic. It would take in the Jira Issue instance and return a new Hash in the desired format.

```rb
def assigned_task_list
  assigned_tasks.map do |jira_issue|
    IssueTransformer.new(jira_issue).transform
  end
end


# issue_transformer.rb

class IssueTransformer
  attr_reader :jira_issue

  def initialize(jira_issue)
    @jira_issue = jira_issue
  end

  def transform
    {
      key: key,
      desired_time_to_resolution: desired_time_to_resolution,
      time_to_resolution: time_to_resolution,
      name: name,
      email: email,
      status: status
    }
  end

  private

  def key
    jira_issue.key
  end

  def desired_time_to_resolution
    jira_issue.customfield_14777.dig('ongoingCycle', 'remainingTime', 'friendly')
  end

  # etc.
end
```

That's likely overkill for now, @Yakov's suggestion of just wrapping the logic in private methods is probably the way to go. But if you need to extend the transformation/extraction logic any further, something like this (with its own unit tests) would be a good idea, to keep the logic separate.